Unable to Install Ubuntu 24.04 on a Biostar motherboard
I've been attempting to install Ubuntu 22.04 onto my new Biostar motherboard and I keep running into the issue where it's saying "Failed to start systemd-journald. service • Journal Service". I installed the ISO file into a bootable USB using Rufus. Once booting it gets as far as that and then gets stuck in a loop trying to start systemd.
Boot screen:

Hardware is as follows:
   Biostar TB360-BTC Pro 2.0 V.6
   Intel Core i7-9700k 9th gen
   Samsung M378A1G43EB1-CPB 8GB PC4-2133P 2Rx8 Desktop Memory RAM
   Silicon power 256GB M.2 SSD SATA III

Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available. And SSD firmware also? At top it says no hostname? Is that not input on screen where you add password? Or is this just boot of live installer?

@oldfred yes sir I’ve updated the latest firmware for the BIOS and SSD. No password, it’s just the boot of the installer. I’ve noticed on the BIOS settings that my total memory does not match up to the SSD memory but then when I go to check each of the ports it’s reading the 250GB. Should that have something to do with it?

Can you boot to the live mode to test system?

@oldfred I’m unsure what you mean boot to live mode, everything I’m finding regarding live mode is installing Ubuntu into bootable flash drive and running it without installing it. But I can’t even get Ubuntu to run it’ll stay in the motherboard screen with the Ubuntu logo loading, I click ESC and that’s where I’m able to see the fault for systemd. It won’t let me do anything not even get into the bios so I’m forced to restart the computer. Is there something I’m missing regarding booting up in live mode?

Then can you use Safe boot. If an install then the recovery mode. This adds nomodeset to grub boot parameters.

@oldfred I booted up Ubuntu under nomodeset and then gave me the trouble code “PCI’s bus error severity=correctable type=physical layer” so this lead to me check all my physical connections in my motherboard come to find out the motherboard has two PCIe power ports and I only had one plugged in. After plugging it in and restarting the machine it now boots up Ubuntu. Thank you so much for guiding me until I found the issue, much appreciated!

@user535733 gotcha buddy no worries, first time using this forum not really sure how it works when something gets "solved". thank you for the clarification and apologies for my ignorance.

First you have to validate the checksum of the iso image file.

I booted up Ubuntu under nomodeset and then gave me the trouble code “PCIe bus error severity=correctable type=physical layer” so this lead to me check all my physical connections in my motherboard come to find out the motherboard has two PCIe power ports (had to make sure both PCIe power ports were plugged in!!!) thank you @oldfred for the guidance. thank you @user535733 for letting me know how to properly add the solution.

Please didn't put SOLVED in the question title. After the required wait time, accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.

@user68186 ok I see it now, I will make sure to turn it green once the required time passes. thank you for the clarification

Thank you for taking the time to write the answer.
